# Ransack gem and endless scrolling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ransack

```
  @q = @integration.profiles.search(params[:q])
  @profiles = @q.result.where(found: true).select("profiles.*").group("profiles.id, profiles.email").includes(:integration_profiles).order("CAST( translate(meta_data -> '#{params[:sort_by]}', ',', '') AS INT) DESC NULLS LAST").page(params[:page]).per_page(20)
```

This works perfectly when no search performed.... when doing a search:

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/integrations/64?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q%5Bbio_or_topics_or_title_or_company_cont_any%5D=&q%5Btitle_cont%5D=&q%5Bcompany_cont%5D=&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D=toronto&sort_by=twitter_followers&q%5Bfacebook_username_not_eq%5D=&q%5Btwitter_username_not_eq%5D=&q%5Blinkedin_username_not_eq%5D=&q%5Blocation_not_eq%5D=&commit=Search
```

But the endless scrolling breaks:

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/integrations/64?commit=Search&page=3&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=toronto&sort_by=twitter_followers&utf8=%E2%9C%93&_=1402337761650

$('.append-me').append( '<div class=\"row profile-list\">\n        <\/div>' );

profileBind();
    $('.pagination').remove();
```

Which is happening due to encoding `&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D=toronto` to `&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=toronto`

Should mention I am using the Will_Paginate gem for my pagination `<%= will_paginate @profiles, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails, class: 'pagination pagination-sm' %>`